# Связь между классами

Tags: java, классы

Добрый день. Предположим, что есть два класса. Первый обеспечивает работу с бд, второй тянет что то из сети. В первом классе необходимо использовать результаты работы второго, однако вся работа во втором классе выполняется в отдельном потоке. Первое решение, которое приходит на ум из первого класса проверять статус потока во втором, а по завершению забирать нужные данные. Можно ли сделать это проще?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону java.util.concurrent; http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/

Comment: Я немного углубился в эту тему, почему просто не использовать PropertyChangeListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте про паттерн [Observer](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наблюдатель_(шаблон_проектирования)). По сути объекты одного класса передают себя в другой класс чтобы их методы вызвали когда работа будет завершена

Answer (score 2):

Используйте очереди. Первый поток (является поставщиком данных) читает данные из БД и ставит задачу на обработку в очередь. Второй поток (является потребителем данных) берет задачу из очереди и выполянет с ней необходимые действия.

Comment: @nekaneka потому что это частное решение, присущее Java Beans. Я предлагаю общую парадигму по разделению ответственности за создание и обработку задач. См. producer/consumer.

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО все эти способы работы через потоки достаточно сложны и такие багогенерирующие.

В данном конкретном случае, описанном ТС, есть вполне естественный способ организации работы и без прямых коммуникаций между потоками. Делаем так:

1. На отдельный поток с расписанием сажаем то что будет ходить в сеть. Результатом его работы является обновление записей в БД (удаление, добавление, обновление) - важно все это делать с использованием транзакций
2. Далее также на отдельном потоке (как вариант в юай треде) сажаем того, кто будет работать с БД - показывать/отображать.

Весь фокус такого подхода состоит в том, что для коммуникации между потоками используется БД, которая неявно поддерживает синхронизацию (через механизм транзакций). Прелесть в том, что не надо специально заботиться о синхронизированных методах общения между тредами, ожидания, завершения, семафоры, локи и проч. мультитредовой муйне. Все происходит ну как бы автоматом.

Comment: Это по сути реализация очереди, только за пределами одного процесса. Кстати, такая схема тоже довольно багогенерирующая. Можно наломать дров на выборке задач и их удалении из БД. Естественно при условии использования нескольких консьюмеров.